# What are Message function and Message variant in IDOC Partner profile?

Tags: edi, idoc

What is the use of message variant and message function in IDoc partner profile? Which one to be used as per the requirement?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/1364007

Comment: Please consider that hi, thanks, regards and so on are considered like "noise" (in the sense of "quality of signal"); stackoverflow is a Q&A site for "[ask questions, get answers, no **distractions**](https://stackoverflow.com/tour); it's all about directly focusing on the question; useful when searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As above mentioned they are key to uniquely identifying a process code/Function Module for processing of the incoming or outgoing IDOCs. A couple of examples are company, plant specific IDOC processing. If you perform any custom processing we can read this value from within a user exit and functions to process differently based on the value.

Its also useful for further selection of IDOCS in reports as shown below.

Note a simple suggestion, define a standard for their use and publish it internally, over time things can get messy.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

They are used to differentiate the use-cases of your IDocs.

Each message type means some business function/object, for example `ORDRSP` is a purchase order confirmation, and if you wanna use it, for example, for distribution of orders to CRM and SRM systems simultaneously, you can create separate variants (or functions) like this

[image]

You can create function **CRM** with variants **001** and **002** if you have two CRM systems in order to differentiate IDocs in BD87.

Here how it is explained in [SAP Help "Inbound Partner Profile"](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8f3819b0c24149b5959ab31070b64058/7.0.36/en-US/4b66af60dfb201bae10000000a42189b.html):

> The message is described by three parameters: The message type is based on EDIFACT message types: for example, a purchase order is of type "ORDERS". You can further subdivide the message type using the message code and function.